# Can I get SAS to concatenate and entire folder of data sets?

Tags: sas

I'm working with data that seem to be split into nearly arbitrary sets from year to year. What I would like to do is to be able to start by concatenating all of the .sas7bdat files in a single library. How would I go about this?

Alternatively, if I know all of the possible names that files in the library might be assigned (but many are potentially missing from any given library), how can I get SAS to ignore missing files? For instance, say that I know all of the .sas7bdat files in my library have one of the names "set01", "set02", "set03" or "set04". If a particular library ("L") is missing one of these, then the data step:

```
DATA temp;
  SET L.set01 L.set02 L.set03 L.set04;
  RUN;
```

will produce an error. Assuming that I know that at least one of these exists, is there an option that will tell SAS to ignore the missing ones?

(I understand that these are two totally different questions, but either would solve my immediate problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SAS there is an easy way for SAS to automatically choose the datasets that start with some common name, you can use following statement:

```
data temp;
 set L.set0: ; /*It will search for all datasets that start with set0 and will set only those which are available*/
run;
```

Does it answer your query?

## Second approach

```
libname L "Y:\Test Data";

proc sql;
  select strip("L."||memname) into :DSNAME separated by ' '
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='L';
quit;

/* Main final DS*/
data want;
  set &DSNAME;
run;
```

It will extract all Dataset names in L directory and will create macro variable DSNAME such as : L.set01 L.oth02 etc. , common names won't matter here..

Comment: Yes, thanks! (Would it work to just use "set L.: ;" or must there be a non-empty prefix?

Comment: no, you need to give some common beginning characters, just an Underscore(_) will also work, like .. set L._: .. Otherwise you can use proc sql to pull all the names of datasets in a library into a macro variable .. see my updated answer with second approach